# PHP - Module based functions in "core" module object

Tags: php, laravel, software-design

For the last weeks (and months) I'm building a module-based software using Laravel (newest 8.x) but I'm struggling with a problem now.

Let's say my software is used by three types of companies with different economic sectors:

1. Financial institute: Managing user's bank accounts
2. IT company: Supporting people in computer technics
3. Supermarket: Storing visitors purchases

I also decided to make a so-called "core" module which contains functionality for all types of companies. For example, every of those three have customers, so I have a model called "Customer".

Laravel is an amazing framework which also supports relationships. I could call some methods from a customer object like:

**1. $customer->bankAccounts();**

```
/**
 * @return HasMany Returns all bank accounts that belongs to this customer.
 */
public function bankAccounts() {
    return $this->hasMany('Modules\\Financial\\Models\\BankAccount');
}
```

**2. $customer->devices();**

```
/**
 * @return HasMany Returns all devices that belongs to this customer.
 */
public function devices() {
    return $this->hasMany('Modules\\IT\\Models\\Device');
}
```

**3. $customer->purchases();**

```
/**
 * @return HasMany Returns all purchases that belongs to this customer.
 */
public function purchases() {
    return $this->hasMany('Modules\\Supermarket\\Models\\Purchase');
}
```

My problem is the following:

When distributing the software to my customers (these companies), they should only use their related modules. An IT company does not need the module which is used by supermarkets. Or a supermarket does not need the software module that is used by a financial insitute.

Since every every module is based on a "core" module, I can't (and don't really want) to add all of these methods (examples 1, 2 and 3) into the "Customer" model. I'm looking for a way to call methods from $customer somehow without defining all of them inside of it.

I hope, I explained it understandable. If you guys have any (great) ideas how to solve this problem or another way to do this, I would be very grateful.

Stay healthy.

Comment: Move "modules" to packages and include it with composer - only needed.

Comment: @Maksim But then how to call a module-related function from an object which is located in the core?

Comment: Make core package. Make module package. In module package use this (one minute googling): https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#dynamic-relationships

Comment: @Maksim Easy to say "one minute googling" if you know what to search for and what this technic is called. I'll take a deep look into it, thank you.